# Expectation of constant matrix sandwiched between two random matrices

Tags: covariance-matrix, matrix, wishart-distribution

I have a $N\times P$ random matrix $X$ with i.i.d. coefficients from a standard normalized Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. The corresponding Wishart matrix is
$$W = \frac{1}{P}X X^{\top}$$
Calculating the expectation value of this gives me
$$\mathbb{E}W \propto \mathbb{1}_N$$

I'm currently dealing with a problem where I'm facing a slightly modified matrix looking like
$$\tilde{W} = X D X^{\top}$$
where $D$ is a $P \times P$ diagonal matrix looking like $D=\mathrm{diag}(a + b, b, \ldots, b)$ and I want to calculate
$$\mathbb{E}\tilde{W}= ?$$

My attempt was to rewrite $D$ as $$D=a \vec{y}_1 \vec{y}_1^{\top} + b\mathbb{1}_P,$$
where $\vec{y}_1 = (1, 0, 0, \ldots)^{\top}$, and then insert it back into my expression to get
$$\mathbb{E}\tilde{W}= a\mathbb{E}X\vec{y}_1 \vec{y}_1^{\top}X^{\top} + b\mathbb{1}_N$$
but I'm really not sure if this is the correct way to do it and how to correctly evaluate the remaining expectation... I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice and help with this problem, thank you!